# How do I use microdata to mark up movie listings?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

I'm trying to use microdata to explain clearly to Google about our little film club. I've pored back and forth over schema.org and established the three major classes I need are Movie, MovieTheater and Event.

However, the way that it seems I am am required to lay out the code is counterintuitive.

It seems logical to me that a PLACE (MovieTheater) would hold an EVENT at which they would be showing a MOVIE.

But it seems that isn't possible, since there's no way to put a MOVIE inside an EVENT.

The only way it seems I can list these things as a single entity is to put the MOVIE outermost, containing an EVENT which takes place at a MOVIETHEATER. But then if I want to list more than one MOVIE, I'd have to repeat all the MOVIETHEATER data beneath the MOVIE object, resulting in a lot of unnecessary HTML.

So, have I read it wrong or missed something; or is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're right.
Use [microdata's](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) *itemref* in order not to duplicate MovieTheater description. Like in example

```
In this example, a single license statement is applied to two works, using itemref from the items representing the works:

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Photo gallery</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>My photos</h1>
  <figure itemscope itemtype="http://n.whatwg.org/work" itemref="licenses">
   <img itemprop="work" src="images/house.jpeg" alt="A white house, boarded up, sits in a forest.">
   <figcaption itemprop="title">The house I found.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure itemscope itemtype="http://n.whatwg.org/work" itemref="licenses">
   <img itemprop="work" src="images/mailbox.jpeg" alt="Outside the house is a mailbox. It has a leaflet inside.">
   <figcaption itemprop="title">The mailbox.</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <footer>
   <p id="licenses">All images licensed under the <a itemprop="license"
   href="http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php">MIT
   license</a>.</p>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

BTW you can write your comments and proposals about schema.org at [public-vocabs@w3.org](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/)

Comment: Hi thanks. I did latterly stumble upon some other questions and answers mentioning itemref, but there's nothing on the schema.org website about itemref at all.

Comment: Because schema.org doesn't describe the microdata standard, it describes metadata you can use with the microdata standard. Check the [HTML5 microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html#attr-itemref) specs